# Using Google Groups for access rights - not working

Tags: google-app-maker

Using Google Groups for giving access to an App Maker application should be possible (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/getting-started/faq#group_sharing). However, it is not working.

Now, I've tried this with two separate accounts in my company's domain, but I get the error: "Sorry, you don't have access to this application."

I'm using an intra-organizational Google Group (and organizational accounts), and have tried two different ones, another one newly created for the purpose of testing. I've tried giving both admin access and normal access through the group, not working.

I'm using the "Only allow access to specific users" option, and without that, access works just fine, and giving the rights directly without the group works. My Google account is a manager in the group(s), so I can see the members.

Creating a new clean app and trying this on it does not resolve the issue. I have also waited enough time for any member additions to groups to take effect.

Is this a bug, organizational settings doing something odd or what gives?

Comment: Yes, it seems so, thank you! But I have to ask you, did you inspect it further? Because it seems that the access rights do no change when the group is altered: if I add a group to the access rights, and PersonA is in that group at that moment, they will have access whether they're a member of that group or not at a later moment. I.e. App Maker uses my account to check who is in that group, but that information will not be updated as the group is updated later on (unless I remove and re-add that group into access rights).

Comment: Haven't tested that. Will do so and get back to you with more info. Pretty weird to be honest, that would totally defeat the purpose of using groups.

Comment: The access rights do change. It might take a couple of hours to take effect (especially when deleting a member of a group). When adding a member, it takes effect almost immediately. So, this is not a bug, you just have to be patient.

Comment: Okay, so it is! Thank you for testing it on your part!